# ¿Como puedo hacer la letra mas gruesa al estilo font-weigth:800; en mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

Tengo una duda, tengo un pdf, donde tengo una palabra solamente para resolver mi pregunta nada mas ya que he probado todo lo que he encontrado por ahi

Resulta que tengo esto:

```
<?php  

    require_once '../plugins/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $html = '
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"style="font-size:19px;font-weight:900;"><b>RESULTADOS</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ';
    
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'Letter','default_font' => 'arial']);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();

?>
```

> Les pongo un ejemplo sencillo para mayor entendimiento de mi problema,
> ya que donde debo implementar esta funcion es un archivo cargado de
> codigo con conexion a base de datos y no se entenderia si pusiera
> todo, ya que mi problema solamente es el que explico a continuacion

Lo que necesito es que la palabra "RESULTADOS" sea mas gruesa, al estilo `arial black` que es una fuente gruesa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es lo mas grueso que he podido dejarlo con la etiqueta `<b></b>`

Pero quisiera algo asi (inserto imagen de word como ejemplo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si se entiende pero en la imagen donde se muestra la palabra el grosor es mayor al de la imagen del pdf

- LO QUE HE PROBADO

He buscado distintas maneras de mandar a llamar a `arial black` como `font-family:arial black;` o de otras maneras utilizando `'default_font' => 'arialBlack'` (al menos asi veo que esta escrito en el archivo `FontVariables.php`) Pero nada me funciona.

Ademas intente usar `font-weight:900;` pero leyendo la documentacion de `mpdf` parece ser que lo unico que se puede utilizar es `font-weight:normal | bold;` solo esas dos opciones por lo que me limita el grosor de la letra

Les agradeceria su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De echo lo estás haciendo bien. Yo te sugeriría que bajes una fuente de tu gusto y la integres a tu librería. Ya que la Arial no te dará para lo que requieres.

Adapté tu código:

```
<?php  
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $html = '
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-size:80px; font-weight:900;"><b>EvilFearzZ</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ';
    
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'Letter','default_font' => 'Matiz']);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
?>
```

1. Ve a cualquier banco de fuentes y descarga la de tu agrado, yo baje
   [Matiz.ttf](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Matiz?filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=black&filter%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D=bold&sort=popular)
2. Descarga el zip de la fuente y descomprímelo.
3. Agrega la fuente o tus fuentes al directorio `/mpdf/ttfonts`
4. Edita `/mpdf/config_fonts.php` (si usas una version antigua) o `/mpdf/src/config/FontVariables.php` (version nueva) para
   agregar una entrada de fuentes.

Por ejemplo te encontras algo así:

```
"sun-extb" => [
    'R' => "Sun-ExtB.ttf",
],
"unbatang" => [/* Korean */
    'R' => "UnBatang_0613.ttf",
],
"windsong" => [/* Nueva fuente windsong*/
    'R' => "windsong.ttf",
],
"matiz" => [/* Nueva fuente matiz*/
    'R' => "matiz.ttf",
],
],
```

Como puedes ver, en ese fragmento he agregado dos fuentes. y la salida es algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

`mPDF` a partir de su versión 4.2 soporta una caracteristica llamada `falseBoldWeight` o "**negrita falsa**", la cual agrega un contorno exterior para simular un grosor superior al que tiene la fuente por defecto.

```
...
$mpdf->falseBoldWeight = 8;

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p style="font-family: Arial"><b>RESULTADOS</b><p>');
$mpdf->Output();
...
```

Los valores recomendados oscilan entre 0 y 10.

Revisa [la documentación aquí...](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/falseboldweight.html)